# What's the translation that brings one 2D polygon completely inside another?

Tags: geometry

Given two 2D polygons, how do I calculate the shortest translation that brings the first inside the second?

1. Assume there is a solution (i.e. the first does in fact fit inside the second)
2. Prefer a simple algorithm over completeness of solution. For example if the algorithm is simplified by making assumptions about the shapes having a certain number of sides, being concave, etc. then make those assumptions.

I can imagine a brute force solution, where I first calculate which are the offending vertices that lie outside the initial polygon. I'd then iterate through these external vertices and find the closest edge to each. Then I'm stuck. Each distance from an external vertex to an edge creates a constraint (a "need to move"). I then need to solve this system of constraints to find the movement that fulfills them all without creating any new violations.

Comment: What have you thought so far? In other words, SO is not meant to do your home work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be a general solution, but here is at least a point to start with:

We want to move the green polygon into the red polygon. We use several translations. Each translation is defined by a start point and an end point.

Step 1: Start point is the **mid-point** between the left-most vertex and the right-most vertex in green polygon. End point, same criterion with the red polygon:

[image]

Step 2: Start point is the mid-point between the top-most vertex and the low-most vertex. End point, same criterion with the red polygon:

[image]

Notice that setps 1 & 2 are kind of centering. This method with mid points is similar to use the bounding boxes. Other way would be using circumcircles, but they are hard to get.

Step 3: Find the vertex in red polygon closest to an edge in the green polygon. You will need to iterate over all of them. Find the line perpendicular to that edge:

[image]

Well, this is not perfect. Depending on the given polygons it's better to proceed the other way: closest vertex in green to edges in red. Choose the smallest distance.

Finally, move the green polygon along that line:

[image]

If this method doesn't work (I'm sure there are cases where it fails), then you can also move the inner polygon along a line (a red edge or a perpendicular) that solves the issue. And continue moving until no issues are found.

Comment: Really elegant how the use of the bisecting lines saves a full iteration over vertices. Couldn't you just superimpose the centroids of the shapes to achieve a similar effect though? I.e. step 1 & 2 is "perform the translation that aligns the centroids". I guess calculating the centroid would be expensive though.

Comment: Centroids calculation is an weighted average of (x,y), not expensive to get. Bounding boxes, circumcircles, centroids,... I think no way is perfect for no regular polygons.